# How to get EPC without printing a label?

Tags: python, rfid, zebra-printers, zpl

We are coding a Zebra ZT410 printer to print RFID labels with information stored in a SQL Database using Python. We are trying to print an abridged version of the EPC on each label, however we cannot get the EPC without the printer printing a blank label.

```py
re = "^XA^RMN^RS8^FN0^RFR,H^FS^HV0^XZ"
q = re.encode("ASCII")
s.sendall(q)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

The Code above returns the EPC just like we need it to, however the printer prints a blank label every time the code is run. We need a way to do this without the printer spitting out a blank label every time. Is this possible? If not, is there a way to make the printer go back one label so we can reuse the blank ones ?

Comment: Have you tried sending your ZPL commands without the begin/end label? How about trying a print quantity of 0?

Comment: @EdHayes3 no we haven't, we'll try that. Thank you

Comment: Did either of those work?

Comment: @EdHayes3 it did not work, it seems to go into some sort of endless loop when i try running it without the begin/end label commands

Comment: If you are trying to print the RFID value on the label, why not read and print at the same time? Rather than Read->Retrieve->Store->Format->Print, try Format->Read/Print->Retrieve->Store.

Comment: For `^RS8` Are you using all the defaults for parameter 2-8? `^RSt,p,v,n,e,a,c,s`
For `^RFR,H` Are you using all the defaults for parameters 3-5? `^RFo,f,b,n,m`
Have you tried `^MMa,b`? I'd guess you want `^MMF,N`

Comment: @EdHayes3 is there a way to Format->Read/Print->Retrieve->Store? That might be what we need I just don't know how to do it

Comment: Just take the ZPL code you were going to use to print the label, and add it to the code that is used to retrieve the RFID details. Note, though, I have never used a zebra printer to do anything with RFIDs. There must be a white paper that Zebra can provide that will walk you through a few simple examples.